# Не получается настроить правила ЧПУ в YII2

Tags: yii2

Помогите разобраться в чем дело. Не работают правила в urlManager

```
'rules' => [
                '/<c>' => 'site/category/',
                '/category/<alias>' => 'site/product',
                '/robots.txt' => '/web/robots.txt',
                '/news/page/<page:\d+>' => 'news/index',//чпу для пагинации ! РАБОТАЕТ
                '/news/post/<p>'=>'news/post', //чпу для вывода ссылки на статью !НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
            ],
```

Хочу получить ссылку типа [https://site.ru/news/post/имя_поста](https://site.ru/news/post/%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)

А получаю [https://site.ru/news/post?p=имя_поста](https://site.ru/news/post?p=%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)

Ссылка в виде выглядит так

```
<a href="<?= Url::to('/news/post?p=' . $post->alias); ?>" class="btn btn-primary ">Читать</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

нужно поднять правило. до него не доходит.

```
'rules' => ['/news/post/<p>'=>'news/post',
            '/<c>' => 'site/category/',
            '/category/<alias>' => 'site/product',
            '/robots.txt' => '/web/robots.txt',
            '/news/page/<page:\d+>' => 'news/index',
        ],
```

Comment: спасибо. попробую, отпишусь как результат